# Is there a way to replace default Windows OpenGL software renderer?

Tags: windows, opengl

When an OpenGL application on windows is run in a VM or over remote desktop, it generally reverts to Microsoft's OpenGL implementation. Is there a way I could seemlessly have it revert to another software renderer instead (i.e. MESA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. If you want to use MESA, you have to actually use MESA.

The closest thing you could do with this is to use DLL injection to create your own opengl32.dll and put it between the real one and your application. You'd farm any API calls to either the regular one or to MESA, as needed.